# Convolutional layer in Python using Numpy - with Strides

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conv-neural-network, stride

My question is highly related to this one, from which I copied the definition: [Convolutional layer in Python using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085669/convolutional-layer-in-python-using-numpy).

I am trying to implement a convolutional layer in Python using Numpy. The input is a 4-dimensional array of shape [N, H, W, C], where:

- N: Batch size
- H: Height of image
- W: Width of image
- C: Number
  of channels

The convolutional filter is also a 4-dimensional array of shape [F, F, Cin, Cout], where

- F: Height and width of a square filter
- Cin: Number of input channels (Cin = C)
- Cout: Number of output channels

With no padding and a stride of S, the output should be a 4-dimensional array of shape [N, (H - F + 1) // S, (W - F + 1) // S, Cout].

For a fixed stride of S=1, this can be done efficiently with the following code:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def conv2d(a, b):
    Hout = a.shape[1] - b.shape[0] + 1
    Wout = a.shape[2] - b.shape[1] + 1

    a = as_strided(a, (a.shape[0], Hout, Wout, b.shape[0], b.shape[1], a.shape[3]), a.strides[:3] + a.strides[1:])

    return np.tensordot(a, b, axes=3)
```

Can anyone help me on how to implement a variable stride of S? As mentioned above I understand the output shape, just not the strides.

Comment: What do mean by variable stride?  Just another value than 1?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I want to make it work for any valid value of S

Comment: To answer this I'd make make a smallish `a`, and try some alternatjve shape and strides in `as_strided`.  While I have some experience with this, it's sufficiently distant that I have to combine reasoning with trial and error.

Comment: Any chance you could give it a shot? I'm getting the shapes to work, but not the values

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below implementation. Argument `s` represents the stride value.

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def conv2d(a, b, s=1):
    Hout = (a.shape[1] - b.shape[0]) // s + 1
    Wout = (a.shape[2] - b.shape[1]) // s + 1
    Stride = (a.strides[0], a.strides[1] * s, a.strides[2] * s, a.strides[1], a.strides[2], a.strides[3])

    a = as_strided(a, (a.shape[0], Hout, Wout, b.shape[0], b.shape[1], a.shape[3]), Stride)

    return np.tensordot(a, b, axes=3)

# test
conv2d(x, kernel, 2)
```