# Reshaping before as_strided for optimisation

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network, tensor, numpy-einsum

```py
def forward(x, f, s):
    B, H, W, C = x.shape # e.g. 64, 16, 16, 3
    Fh, Fw, C, _ = f.shape # e.g. 4, 4, 3, 3 
    # C is redeclared to emphasise that the dimension is the same
    
    Sh, Sw = s # e.g. 2, 2

    strided_shape = B, 1 + (H - Fh) // Sh, 1 + (W - Fw) // Sw, Fh, Fw, C

    x = as_strided(x, strided_shape, strides=(
        x.strides[0], 
        Sh * x.strides[1], 
        Sw * x.strides[2], 
        x.strides[1], 
        x.strides[2], 
        x.strides[3]), 
    )

    # print(x.flags, f.flags)

    # The reshaping changes the einsum from 'wxyijk,ijkd' to 'wxyz,zd->wxyd'
    f = f.reshape(-1, f.shape[-1])
    x = x.reshape(*x.shape[:3], -1) # Bottleneck!
    
    return np.einsum('wxyz,zd->wxyd', x, f, optimize='optimal')
```

(On the contrary, the variant *without* the reshapes uses `return np.einsum('wxyijk,ijkd->wxyd', x, f)`)

For reference, here are the flags for `x` and `f` before reshaping:

```
x.flags:

C_CONTIGUOUS : False
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : False
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False


f.flags:

C_CONTIGUOUS : True
F_CONTIGUOUS : False
OWNDATA : True
WRITEABLE : True
ALIGNED : True
WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

Interestingly the major bottleneck in the routine is *not* the `einsum`, but rather the reshaping (flattening) of `x`. I understand that `f` does not suffer from such problems since its memory is C-contiguous, so the reshape amounts to a quick internal modification without changing the data - but since `x` is not C-contiguous (and does not own its data, for that matter), the reshape is far more expensive since it involves changing the data/fetching non-cache-aligned data often. This, in turn, results from the `as_strided` function performed on `x` - the modification of the strides must be in such a manner as to disturb the natural ordering. (FYI, the `as_strided` is incredibly fast, and should be fast no matter what strides are passed to it)

Is there a way to achieve the same result without incurring the bottleneck? Perhaps by reshaping `x` before using `as_strided`?

---

Also note, for almost 100% of applications:
B: [1-64], H, W: [1-60], C: [1-8]
Fh, Fw: [1-12]

---

I'm also including some graphs here, for variation of timing with a variation in the tensor dimensions `B` (batch size), as well as `H, W` (image size) on my device (as you can see, the one involving reshape is already reasonably competitive with Tensorflow):

[image: Variation with batch size]
[image: Variation with image size]

---

EDIT: An interesting find - the reshape-algorithm beats the non-reshape-algorithm by a factor of 5 on the CPU, but when I use the GPU (i.e. using CuPy instead of NumPy), both algorithms are equally fast (around twice as fast as TensorFlow's forward pass)

Comment: The basic issue is that `as_strided` creates a `view`, but any reshape after makes a full size copy.  The view makes 'virtual' copies, the reshape real copies.

Comment: Have you tried reshaping `x` to 2d before the striding? Looks like they pass through that operation without change.  But I haven't examined this in detail.

Comment: Have you verified that `'wxyz,zd->wxyd'` is faster than `'wxyijk,ijkd'`?  I recall suggesting that consolidation of `ijk` to `z` so you could use `matmul`, but it isn't necessary for `einsum`.  But since `einsum` seems to delegate the task to `matmul` where obvious, that might  help.

Comment: @hpaulj yep, the two reshapes + `'wxyz,zd->wxyd'` is indeed faster than no reshapes + `'wxyijk,ijkd'`

Comment: One more comment - I've never tried to use `einsum` (or `matmul`) on a large `as_strided` array.  So I don't know whether they avoid turning the view into a copy or not.  `as_strided`is most useful when trying to consolidate values, such as taking `mean` on moving windows.

Comment: @hpaulj An interesting find - the reshape-algorithm beats the non-reshape-algorithm by a factor of 5 on the CPU, but when I use the GPU (i.e. using CuPy instead of NumPy), both algorithms are equally fast! (around twice as fast as TensorFlow's forward pass)

Comment: wait, you used `einsum`'s optimization algorithms with the reshaped version, but not the non-reshaped version?  That might be the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Reshaping of the strided array is a little bit costly, for the reasons you've mentioned (copy on non-contiguous array), but not as costly as you think. `np.einsum` can actually be a bottleneck in your application, depending on tensor sizes. As mentioned in [Convolutional layer in Python using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085669/convolutional-layer-in-python-using-numpy), `np.tensordot` can be a good candidate to replace `np.einsum`.

Just to give you a quick example:

```py
x = np.arange(64*221*221*3).reshape((64, 221, 221, 3))
f = np.arange(4*4*3*5).reshape((4, 4, 3, 5))
s = (2, 2)

B, H, W, C = x.shape # e.g. 64, 16, 16, 3
Fh, Fw, C, _ = f.shape # e.g. 4, 4, 3, 3 
Sh, Sw = s # e.g. 2, 2
strided_shape = B, 1 + (H - Fh) // Sh, 1 + (W - Fw) // Sw, Fh, Fw, C
print(strided_shape)
# (64, 109, 109, 4, 4, 3)
```

after initializing the variables, we can test timings of the code parts

```py
%timeit x_strided = as_strided(x, strided_shape, strides=(x.strides[0], Sh * x.strides[1], Sw * x.strides[2], x.strides[1], x.strides[2], x.strides[3]), )
>>> 7.11 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit f_reshaped = f.reshape(-1, f.shape[-1])
>>> 450 ns ± 7.43 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit x_reshaped = x_strided.reshape(*x_strided.shape[:3], -1) # Bottleneck!
>>> 94.6 ms ± 896 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# einsum without reshape
%timeit np.einsum('wxy...,...d->wxyd', x_strided, f, optimize='optimal')
>>> 809 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# einsum with reshape
%%timeit
f_reshaped = f.reshape(-1, f.shape[-1])
x_reshaped = x_strided.reshape(*x_strided.shape[:3], -1) # Bottleneck!
k = np.einsum('wxyz,zd->wxyd', x_reshaped, f_reshaped, optimize='optimal')
>>> 549 ms ± 3.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# tensordot without reshape
%timeit k = np.tensordot(x_strided, f, axes=3)
>>> 271 ms ± 4.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# tensordot with reshape
%%timeit
f_reshaped = f.reshape(-1, f.shape[-1])
x_reshaped = x_strided.reshape(*x_strided.shape[:3], -1) # Bottleneck!
k = np.tensordot(x_reshaped, f_reshaped, axes=(3, 0))
>>> 266 ms ± 3.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I got similar results with the tensor sizes in your code (i.e. 64, 16, 16, 3 and 4, 4, 3, 3).

As you can see, there is an overhead with resize operation, but it makes matrix operations faster because of continuous data. Please, be aware that results would vary depending on cpu speed, cpu architecture/generation etc.

Comment: The thing is, I don't expect `einsum` to be a problem at all, especially since I'm only contracting along one index. I was wondering whether it's possible to keep the speed of `einsum` along with improving the speed of the reshape, by reshaping the tensor `x` before `as_strided` messes up its data ordering.